# Array of typescript user-defined types/objects as property in Lit v2

Tags: typescript, lit-element, lit

I would like to convert my existing Javascript CustomElements/WebComponents (made with Lit v1 and ported to v2) to TypeScript.

Example:

```
export class MyElement extends LitElement {
  ...
  @property({type: String})
  name = 'World';
  ...
}
```

... or another one: https://github.com/lit/lit-element-starter-ts/blob/main/src/my-element.ts#L37

How can I define a property as an array of my custom typescript classes?

E.g. something like this:

```
export class MyElement extends LitElement {
  ...
  @property({type: Array<MyCustomClass>})
  customClassArray = [];
  // or: customClassArray = [new MyCustomClass("foo")]; 
  ...
}
```

Comment: That's a runtime type declaration. Typescript types are compile-time only. More info here: https://lit.dev/docs/components/properties/#conversion-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lit's `@property` decorator is all about setting up a reactive property AND reflecting the attribute to the value (and vice versa if you turn on `reflect: true`). However, this conversion for HTML elements is tricky on non-string values, e.g. numbers shall be parsed to an actual number, for a boolean value the existence of the attribute means `true` etc.

That is why Lit needs `type`, to be able to choose the correct converter for the attribute value. Think of it as a type-hint or a converter-type regarding attribute/value conversion. Take a look at
[Lit's default converter](https://github.com/lit/lit/blob/main/packages/reactive-element/src/reactive-element.ts#L230-L270).

Your actual types should be defined in TypeScript.

```
export class YourElement extends LitElement {
  @property({ type: Array })
  customClassArray = new Array<YourCustomClass>();
  // or: customClassArray = [new YourCustomClass()];
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I see you edited L2. I thought Lit would be capable to interpret custom types directly within the property decorator.

Comment: I'm having trouble with this as well. In all questions I'm missing the HTML side. Are you binding this via `<your-element customClassArray="[{...}, {...}]"></your-element>`?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found a solution by myself, quite similiar to @arshia11d answer.

```
import { MyCustomClass } from './MyCustomClass';    

export class MyElement extends LitElement {
      @property({ type: Array }) //Array<MyCustomClass> throws ts(2303) error
      annotations: MyCustomClass[] = [];
    }
```

Type definition:

```
export interface IMyCustomClass {
  label: string;
}

export class MyCustomClass implements IMyCustomClass {
  label: string;

  constructor(
    _label: string
  ) {
    this.label = _label;
  }
}
```